# C# Odd method call casting

Tags: c#, casting

I am encouter the following code snippet, during i try so learn WPF.

```
((DependencyObject)targetObject).SetValue(dp, finalValue);
```

What is code snippet mean? I know that instance method SetValue is going to call, but this (DependencyObject) i really do not understand. It is something to do with casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`targetObject` is cast to `DependencyObject`, so that the `SetValue` method of the `DependencyObject` type can be called.

My guess is `targetObject` is of type object, and so doesn't have the `SetValue` method available - until it is cast.

If you removed the `(DependencyObject)`, it should become clear - the `object` type doesn't have a `SetValue` method.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Kieren's answer -consider the following scenario:

```
public class Base {}
public class Derived : Base
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing stuff!");
    }
}

...
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Derived myDerivedObject = new Derived();        
    Base myObjectAsBase = myDerivedObject; // This is fine because Derived "is a" Base

    // call methods
    myDerivedObject.DoStuff();           // OK - 'Derived' has a 'DoStuff()' method
    myObjectAsBase.DoStuff();            // Compiler error - 'Base' does not have a 'DoStuff()' method
    ((Derived)myObjectAsBase).DoStuff(); // OK - myObjectAsBase is cast to type 'Derived' which has a 'DoStuff()' method
}
```

The example in your question is equivalent to the third case.